# Set a current_profile for a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

A user can has many profiles. Each profile has its own properties. And the user can change from one profile to another anytime, anywhere.

So I want to set a method or variable available in controllers and views where I can set the user's `current_profile` (like devise's `current_user` helper).

We've tried using a `ApplicationController` private method and a `ApplicationHelper` method, but it doesn't work when the user's nickname it's not available (is set through a URL param).

This is the AppController method

```
...
private
  def set_profile
    if params[:username]
      @current_profile ||= Profile.where(username: params[:username]).entries.first
    else
     nil
    end
  end
```

And this is the AppHelper method

```
def current_profile
  unless @current_profile.nil?
    @current_profile
  end
end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Create a lib (for organization purposes) that extends ActionController::Base and define "set_profile" and "current_profile" there as a helper method, then require it and call it on ApplicationController.

application_controller.rb

```
require 'auth'

before_filter :set_profile # sets the profile on every request, if any
```

lib/auth.rb

```
class ActionController::Base
  helper_method :set_profile, :current_profile

  protected

  def set_profile
    if params[:username]
      session[:user_profile] = params[:username]
      ...
    end
  end

  def current_profile
    @current_profile ||= if session[:user_profile]
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end

end
```

That way you can call current_profile anywhere in your code (view and controllers).

Comment: Shouldn't be `ActionController::Base.class_eval do ... end` instead of just `class ActionController::Base ... end`?

Comment: Nope. This is essentially reopening the class in order to add a few methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relation where `User has_many :profiles` you can add a `current:boolean` column on profiles. Then:

```
def set_profile
  if params[:profile_id]
    @current_profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
    @current_profile.current = true
  else
    nil
  end
end

# helper_method
def current_profile
   @current_profile
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`@current_profile` as memeber variable of ApplicationController is not visible in your helper. You should create accessor method in Appcontroller like:

```
def current_profile
  @current_profile
end
```

or via

```
attr_accessor :current_profile
```

And in helper (make sure that accessor in controller is not private):

```
def current_profile
  controller.current_profile
end
```

But you also free to define this as helper only, without involving controller at all:

```
  def current_profile
    if params[:username]
      @current_profile ||= Profile.where(username: params[:username]).first
    end
  end
```

This will automagically cache you database query in `@current_profile` and automagically return nil if there is no param specified. So no need for extra `else` clause and extra `set_...` method

Comment: The thing is that `params[:username]` it is not available in all the application. Only in one point where the user sets it. I want to set it in that point so it is available everywhere.

Comment: Yes `current_profile` is availabe in your whole application, i mean views and controllers. Or maybe you need to persist it across requests ? Then i guess you should use session, like just replace `@current_profile` with `session[:current_profile]`